# Implementing an AccountManager in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, accountmanager

I have been following [this guide](http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) in making an `AccountManager` for Android.  But I am using Xamarin, and I have reached a point where the C# code is too different from the Java code.  The account is on the phone, and I can add an account from the settings screen just fine.  But when I try to access the `AccountManager.AddAccount` method externally, the arguments it takes are different and I do not think they are explained very well in the Xamarin documentation.

[This page in the Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Accounts.AccountManager/) shows that the last two arguments in `AddAccount` are `IAccountManagerCallback` and `Handler` parameters.  I am not sure how to go about implementing these in a way that I can pass them into `AddAccount`.

Just to be clear, what I want to do is call `AddAccount` (which is inside my custom `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`) from a different activity.  When you click "Add Account" in the Android settings screen, it automatically calls the right function.

Comment: Have you looked on Xamarin.Auth. It has build in accounts

Answer (score 1):

I see this was posted a while back but in case it is still of some help to someone this is how I implemented IAccountManagerCallback in Xamarin...

```
    internal static void AddAccount(Activity activity, string type) {
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.Get(activity);
        IAccountManagerCallback callback = new AccountManagerCallback();
        accountManager.AddAccount(type, null, null, null, activity, callback, null);
    }
    private class AccountManagerCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IAccountManagerCallback {
        void IAccountManagerCallback.Run(IAccountManagerFuture future) {
            if (future.IsCancelled) {
                //task was cancelled code
            }
            else if (future.IsDone) {
                //task is completed
                Java.Lang.Object result = future.Result;
                //process result
            }
        }
    }
```